# Recommended way to reach On-Premises API through API Management without premium or developer tier

Tags: azure, api, proxy, azure-api-management

I was looking into to how import an API hosted locally/on-premise withing a internal network.
I found Microsofts documentation on: "Using Azure API Management service with an internal virtual network", but the prerequisites for that (as i understood it) was to either have a Developer or Premium tier on the APIM Resource.

As we want to be able to use the APIM in production environment we cant use the Developer tier and Premium is not profitable at this moment.

What i want to do is to be able to expose the on premises API's endpoints by proxying the endpoints via API Management.

Is there any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of alternatives you could consider to exposing on-premises data, taking into account that the other tiers of APIM can access resources on the internet.

1. [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) + [VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways)
2. [App Service + Hybrid Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections)
3. [Logic Apps + On-Premise Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection)

With these setup, you could set these up as backends to APIM.

Also, you would want to protect these services from the public internet by setting up one or more of the following

- IP Restrictions, if available for the service
- [Mutual Certificate Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates)
- [OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) / [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#ManagedIdentity)

Also, there is a [feature request for supporting Hybrid Connections](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/19684408-apim-hybrid-connection-manager-support-for-accessi) directly in APIM which you could up vote for it to gain traction.